# Import dynamically external JavaScript module in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a Javascript module that looks like:

```
export function test() {
  return "Hello";
}
```

I need to import this script in React.
This is what I tried:

1. Defined a useScript method:

```
const useScript = ({ onLoad } : { onLoad: any }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "module";
    script.src = "remote/path/to/test.js";
    script.onload = onLoad
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, [onLoad]);
};
```

2. Use it to load the script in React component:

```
const getTest = () => {
    window["test"]();
 }

useScript({
  onLoad: getTest
});
```

This gives me the error:

```
window.test is not a function
```

Note, that if I remove `export` from the JS file then it works. However, I need the `export` and not sure why adding export breaks it.
Any clues?

Edit: Tried using `import` like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const getTest = async function() {
        const uri = "https://remote/path/to/test.js";
        const { test } = await import(uri);
        console.log(test());
      }
      getTest();
    }
  }, []);
```

However, this gives the error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `export` transform your file to a module, which has it own scope, so `test` is not added to `window` object anymore. If you need the file on demand consider using [`import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import):

> The `import()` call, commonly called dynamic `import`, is a function-like expression that allows loading an ECMAScript module asynchronously and dynamically into a potentially non-module environment.

In a project bundled by Webpack add `/* webpackIgnore: true */` before your url if it's an external file that Webpack shouldn't look for at build time, like so:

```js
const { test } = await import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ "/test.js");
```

This would import `test` function from this `test.js` file:

```
export function test() {
  return "Hello";
}
```